# How does Stack Overflow handle obsolete answer?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, asking-questions, old-questions

I mean obsolete information like, let's say I have a question:

> How to do `foreach` within JavaScript?

the old answer would be:

> You can't you have to use for-loop.

But JavaScript is now has `Array.forEach()`.
If I or someone create the question again, it likely will be marked as duplicate by moderator and can be closed. However it's not guaranteed that the existing old question has an updated answer.

How to handle a situation like this?

Comment: In that case, why don't you post a new answer to the old question, mentioning "In newer versions of Javascript, you can use ..." or something like that?